# How to create column, from the cumulative column in r?

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(dat=c("11-03","12-03","13-03"), 
c=c(0,15,20,4,19,21,2,10,14), d=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=3))
```

suppose `c` has the cumulative values. I want to create a column `daily` that will look like

`dat     c d daily
1 11-03  0 A 0
2 12-03 15 A 15
3 13-03 20 A 5
4 11-03  4 B 4
5 12-03 19 B 15
6 13-03 21 B 2
7 11-03  2 C 2
8 12-03 10 C 8
9 13-03 14 C 4`

for each value of `d` and `dat` (date wise) a daily change in value is generated from the column `c` has that cumulative value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the `diff` of 'c' after grouping by 'd'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(d) %>%
    mutate(daily = c(first(c), diff(c)))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   d [3]
#  dat       c d     daily
#  <fct> <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
#1 11-03     0 A         0
#2 12-03    15 A        15
#3 13-03    20 A         5
#4 11-03     4 B         4
#5 12-03    19 B        15
#6 13-03    21 B         2
#7 11-03     2 C         2
#8 12-03    10 C         8
#9 13-03    14 C         4
```

---

Or do the difference between the 'c' and the `lag` of 'c'

```
df %>%
   group_by(d) %>%
   mutate(daily = c - lag(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Data.table solution:

```
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, daily:= c - shift(c, fill = 0),by=d]
```

Shift is datatable's lag operator, so basically we subtract from C its previous value within each group.

fill = 0 replaces NAs with zeros, because within each group, there is no previous value (shift(c)) for the first element.